# Loop through the files in a directory/folder, filter them and then read information from them line by line

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I want to cycle over files in a folder, and read some data from them:

```
directory = os.fsencode(directory)
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        file = os.fsdecode(file)
        if file.endswith(".log"):
            with open(file) as f:
                for line in f:
                   extract(line=line))
```

> with open(file) as f: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or
>   directory: b'access.log'

This is 'strange' because the file exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the base path to the file. Use `os.path.join(directory, file)`

**Ex:**

```
directory = os.fsencode(directory)
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    file = os.fsdecode(file)
    if file.endswith(".log"):
        with open(os.path.join(directory, file)) as f:
            for line in f:
               extract(line=line))
```

Comment: I get an error: Can't mix strings and bytes in path components

Comment: I use python 3.7, if I keep a version of directory for join not encoded it works